# why i can't import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener; and LocationRequest, also LocationServices?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location

I am trying to build an android app using android studio that uses the direct user location, and I am got error on import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener; it says it can't resolve symbol 'LocationListener', and also for 'LocationRequest' and 'LocationServices' I tried searching for an answer but I can't figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding the below :

```
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
```

in your app level gradle dependencies and

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

in project level gradle dependencies

note the versions may change based on your SDK config or your preference

Comment: current one is: 
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0 and com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0

check it here:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 7):

Things has changed since 2018, and Gradle 3.0.0. Now you must use:
`implementation` instead of `compile`, in your *`./app/build.gradle`*, in the `dependencies{}` section. Like this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    ...
}
```

Search for *`location`* in the [releases](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) web page.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link for the list of Google Play libraries and you can add the location library.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
```

This should resolve.